# Metro app - How to display images fetched from SQLite?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, bitmap, microsoft-metro

I have to display images from the database, but am unable to convert the byte stream into a image presentable format.

I referred to WP7 project, but not able to do the same stuff here..

```
byte[] blob;
blob = TableName.Table_Image;
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(blob);
WriteableBitmap bimg = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(memStream);
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search, this link helped me.

http://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-irandomaccessstream/#comment-89

Hope this is useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrased straight from production code:

```
byte[] blob = TableName.Table_Image;
if( blob != null && blob.Length > 0 ) {
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
    bmp.SetSource( new MemoryStream( blob ) );

    MyPhoto.Source = bmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static ImageSource FetchImageToImageSource(bytes[] imageBytes)
    {
    var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        WriteableBitmap w = new WriteableBitmap(0, 0);
        w.SetSource(ms);
        return w;
    }
```

This should work.